# Kibana bar chart avg aggregation by field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm new with Elastic and kibana. 
I'm creating my first visualizations in Kibana. I started with what I thought would be something easy: bar chart. However, I am quite lost with the documentation.
I have an index with the following mapping:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "fake": {   ###### classification field
        "type": "long"
      },
      "paper": {   ###### newspaper name
        "type": "text"
      },
      "published": {   ###### published date of the new
        "type": "date"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to implement a test chart with the following aggregation:
Y-Axis: average of field "fake"
X-Axis: newspaper name field (paper).

It should look something like this:
https://www.screencast.com/t/90IpoSnz

This is my configuration for Y-Axis:
https://www.screencast.com/t/466TFuE3osrw

However, when configuring the X-axis I can't see the field "paper" among the available fields. I'm sure it's a problem with my mapping but I don't know how I should define that field in order to have it selectable.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though my field was showing on the index pattern settings I realised it wasn't marked as aggregatable hence I had to redefine my index mappings by adding an analyzer to my field:
From

```
paper = Text()
```

I changed to:

```
paper = Text(analyzer='standard', fields={'raw': Keyword()})
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Metrics**

Select metric aggregation for Y-axis as `Average` select field `fake`

**Buckets**

select `X-Axis` as buckets, select Aggregation inside as `Terms` and field `paper`.

Run the visualization and you should see the expected bar chart.

Comment: Thanks Atul but that's what I tried. My field "paper" is not among the fields available: https://www.screencast.com/t/EmTHjr1BZx6

Comment: I think, you need to re-create the `Index Pattern`. 
Go to `Management` tab,
select `Index Patterns`, delete your existing index and recreate index.
While creating new index, make sure that `paper` field is visible there.